# Split dataframes into train_test to fed into CNN

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, train-test-split

I have two dataframes. One with 1065*75000 which is my training matrix and one with 1065*1 which is my target matrix. I want to split them into training and testing so i can fed them to my CNN model. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried following

```py
y = target_dataframe["Target_column"]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = (df_training, y, test_size = 0.2)
```

and

```py
x_train, X_test = train_test_split(df_training)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_target)
```

The cnn is working on both of them but how would i know which one is better approach and if there is something new please share it with me.